# Using a Variable to Construct a Table Path

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query script tool which is run in multiple environments, with many in-script references to the database where the script is running. Rather than have to manually edit each of those instances at run-time, I'd like to set a variable at the top of the script so the database value can be assigned once.

I'd declare the variable so:

```
DECLARE @db VARCHAR(25) = 'some database name'
```

And then I'd like to use that variable in a reference to a table path, e.g.:

```
SELECT 1 FROM @db.sys.partitions
```

Is something like that possible? If so, how could it be constructed? Thanks.

Comment: You can execute dynamic sql like this: `exec('SELECT 1 FROM ' +  @db + '.sys.partitions')`

Comment: Guys, thanks for the responses but I had trouble trying to use EXEC and SQLCMD since some of the references in my script are embedded in other functions. I ended up doing: DECLARE @db VARCHAR(25) = 'some database name' EXEC('USE ' + @db) and then just shortening the table paths.

Answer (score 0):

The following dynamic SQL should work for you:

```
declare @sql_command nvarchar(max)
declare @db varchar(25)
select @db = 'some database name'

select @sql_command = 'SELECT top 1 * FROM '+ @db + '.sys.partitions'
execute sp_executesql @sql_command
```